# Exporting Customized roles from AX 2012 to excel

Tags: excel, x++, user-roles

I wrote a code that exported the user roles that come with AX, yet, the custom roles that have been assigned are not exported. I'm doing a re-assignment on roles and I want every role to be listed. Here's my code that did the first task. Thanks.

```
static void exportSecurityRoles(Args _args)
{
   SysExcelApplication  xlsApplication;
   SysExcelWorkBooks    xlsWorkBookCollection;
   SysExcelWorkBook     xlsWorkBook;
   SysExcelWorkSheets   xlsWorkSheetCollection;
   SysExcelWorkSheet    xlsWorkSheet;
   SysExcelRange        xlsRange;
   CustTable            custTable;
   int                  row = 1;
   str                  fileName;
   SecurityRole            securityRole;
   SecurityUserRole        UserRole;
   SysUserInfo             userInfo;
   OMUserRoleOrganization roleOrganization;
   OMInternalOrganization internalOrganization;
   ;
   //Filename
   fileName = "C:\\UserRoles.xlsx";
   //Initialize Excel instance
   xlsApplication           = SysExcelApplication::construct();
   //Open Excel document
   //xlsApplication.visible(true);
   //Create Excel WorkBook and WorkSheet
   xlsWorkBookCollection    = xlsApplication.workbooks();
   xlsWorkBook              = xlsWorkBookCollection.add();
   xlsWorkSheetCollection   = xlsWorkBook.worksheets();
   xlsWorkSheet             = xlsWorkSheetCollection.itemFromNum(1);
   //Excel columns captions
   xlsWorkSheet.cells().item(row,1).value("User Id");
   xlsWorkSheet.cells().item(row,2).value("Role");
    xlsWorkSheet.cells().item(row,3).value("Company");
   row++;
   //Fill Excel with CustTable AccountNum and Name fields (only 20 records)
   while select ID from userInfo
        order by id asc
        outer join UserRole
        where UserRole.User == userInfo.Id
            outer join securityRole
            where securityRole.RecId == UserRole.SecurityRole
            outer join roleOrganization
            where roleOrganization.User == userInfo.Id
            && roleOrganization.SecurityRole == UserRole.SecurityRole
                outer join internalOrganization
                    where internalOrganization.RecId == roleOrganization.OMInternalOrganization
   {

      xlsWorkSheet.cells().item(row,1).value( userInfo.Id);
      xlsWorkSheet.cells().item(row,2).value(SysLabel::labelId2String(securityRole.Name));
       xlsWorkSheet.cells().item(row,3).value(internalOrganization.Name ? internalOrganization.Name : "All Company");
      row++;
   }
   //Check whether the document already exists
   if(WinApi::fileExists(fileName))
      WinApi::deleteFile(fileName);
   //Save Excel document
   xlsWorkbook.saveAs(fileName);
   //Open Excel document
   xlsApplication.visible(true);
   //Close Excel
   //xlsApplication.quit();
   //xlsApplication.finalize();

}
```

Comment: Did you check for one of the custom roles if there is data missing in one of the tables of the while select statement?